# Simple json array structure

Tags: javascript, json

i know the next question must seem stupid but i'll do it anyway :)

I've got this structure:

```
{
      "name": "Erjet Malaj",
      "first_name": "Erjet",
      "work": [
        {
          "employer": {
            "id": "110108059015688",
            "name": "Art of Living Foundation"
          },
          "position": {
            "id": "137081429661437",
            "name": "Volunteer"
          },
          "start_date": "0000-00",
          "end_date": "0000-00"
        },
        {
```

I retrieve response.data[i].first_name like this, how am i supposed to retrieve work id?

Comment: `work` doesn't have an ID.  Do you mean the employer ID or position ID?

Comment: Where is work id in the structure?

Comment: work id means employer id OR position Id?.. JGD :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`work` is an array. You need to loop through it

```
var work = response.data[i].work,
    worklen = work.length,
    j, workdetails;

for(j = 0; j < worklen; j++){

    //simplify for readability
    workdetails = work[j];

    //where prop is "employer" or "position"
    workdetails[prop].id 
    workdetails[prop].name
}
```

Comment: Hey, since i'm here, can i please make you a question, so i need to loop throuh all my id's then for each id extract the work id, what am i doing wrong here please?

for(var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){
    var work = response.data[i].work,
    worklen = work.length,
    j, workdetails;

for(j = 0; j < worklen; j++){

    //simplify for readability
    workdetails = work[j];

    //where prop is "employer" or "position"
    workdetails[prop].id 
    workdetails[prop].name
 
 testdiv.innerHTML += workdetails;
}

Comment: @AlAlb: Please edit your question and post the code there. Nothing is worse than multiline-code in comments...

Answer (score 0):

did you try `response.data[i].work.position.id` ?

on second thought, work is an array of objects, so it's accessed like :

`response.data[i].work[0].position.id`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean employer id of a given work

This should get the employer id

```
response.data[i].work[j].employer.id
```

You could also do this (depending on preference)

```
response.data[i].work[j]['employer'].id
```

In this case the work position is j (used as an array indexer), replace j with 0 to tget the first, with 1 to get the second etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `id` for the employer and position of each record in the `work` array.  If you want to loop over a person's work entries and collect those IDs, use:

```
var person = response.data[i];
var work = person.work;

for(var j = 0; j < work.length; ++j) {
    var work_entry = work[j];
    console.log(work_entry.employer.id);
    console.log(work_entry.position.id); 
}
```

The entries in the `work` array are accessed numerically from 0.  The entries themselves are objects, and you can access their properties using `obj_name.property_name` or `obj_name["property_name"]`

Comment: Thanks, this was all i needed, it took me time to understand how it works :)